# How joomla plugin registers itself to a subject

Tags: development, joomla-api, plugin

Its been about a year, that i started using joomla. i.e building some **plugins**, **module** and **components**. 
Now i want to extend my level of knowledge in inside working mechanism of joomla system.

I know events defined in plugin are called after **triggering**, but on a first hand how every plugin **register** itself to joomla's core **eventdispatcher**.

Can anyone clear my confusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do not register itself. This is done by [JPluginHelper::importPlugin()](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/cms/plugin/helper.php#L148) method. See [this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1858258&seqNum=2) for reference. Hope it will make your confusion clear ;)